# Mule - [WARNING] MULE_HOME is not set - displayed when building with Maven

Tags: maven, deployment, environment-variables, mule

I'm trying to deploy a Mule application to Standalone using Maven, but Maven is unable to move my app to the relevant apps folder and I'm given the following warning:

```
[WARNING] MULE_HOME is not set, not copying <app-name>
```

However, MULE_HOME is set, and a simple `echo $MULE_HOME` in Terminal gives the following, which is correct:

```
/opt/mule
```

Is there a known fix to this? Currently having to manually copy to the apps directory.

Comment: It's working fine for me with Maven Mule plug-in 1.9, JDK 1.7 and Maven 3.1. What versions of these are you using?

Comment: Maven Mule Plugin 1.9, JDK 1.7 and Maven 3.2.1 - perhaps an issue in the latest Maven?

Comment: Maybe a compatibility issue between the plug-in and Maven 3.2. Could you give it a shot with 3.1?

Comment: Just given it a go with 3.1.1 - same error. Double checked my bash profile too and MULE_HOME is set to the correct location

Comment: That's very peculiar. You're not doing anything obviously wrong so this feature should just work OOTB. If you run `mvn -X install | grep MULE_HOME` do you see two matches for `env.MULE`?

Comment: I don't see anything when running `mvn -X install | grep MULE_HOME` - although when running a simple `echo $MULE_HOME`, I still get the correct directory, very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out where the issue was here. My standalone instance of Mule is in a directory `/opt/mule-standalone-3.4.0` with an alias `/opt/mule` pointing to the same location. For some reason, Maven didn't like `MULE_HOME` being set to the alias. When amended to point to the actual directory, all worked fine.